# Android emulator on Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, react-native

I want to launch the React Native application on Android emulator using Ubuntu 16.04. Following the react native docs it should be dove by running

```
react-native run-android
```

OR

```
npm run android
```

Both these commands are not working without sudo for some reason, but that's not an issue. The issue is when I run them every time I get the same error:

> Error running adb: No Android device found. Please connect a device
>   and follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options.
>   If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom
>   Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.

[image]

I don't want to connect device via USB and I don't use Genymotion, I just want an emulator. I tried to run the project via Android Studio, but faced with another issue :

> Error: please select Android SDK

[image]

I tried syncing the files, removing the project, restart the studio - nothing. (However I can see the Nexus 5X in the devices list and even start it) 
Please someone help me, I've tried everything I could find - nothing helps

Comment: Genymotion is an emulator....

Comment: I understand, but installation tutorials don't even mention Genymotion, I guess, there's a way to run emulator without Genymorion, right>

Comment: Yes, there is, but you will need to setup the Android SDK in Android Studio for the AVD to work

Answer (score 0):

> Both these commands are not working without sudo for some reason, but
>   that's not an issue.

Probably, this is the root cause.

Because, if you have ever installed your Android SDK / Tools using "sudo" or you installed it into the directories of root user, then those files may not be accessible or executable by a normal account. So, try below steps:

1. Delete the **hidden** dirs `~/.gradle` `~/.idea` `~/.m2` and `~/.android` using command

   `sudo rm -rf ~/.gradle ~/.idea ~/.m2 ~/.android`.

   This step is to clear up your previously installed files with root previlige. If you don't have those folders, ignore this step.
2. Re-install your Android Studio into your normal user home directory, e.g. `~/android`
3. Create your AVDs using the newly installed Android Studio.

Don't use any "**sudo**" for your newly configured environment. Because anything installed with root privilege will go to root directory, i.e. `/`, but not your normal user home dir, i.e. `~/`. If you start your Android Studio with a normal user, usually, it will only be able to refer to your setups under `~/`. This is probable the reason for not being able to find your "installed" Android SDK.